Can not adb push to /data, getting "remote couldn't create file: Permission denied"
This issue is not about the permissions of the file, this is about a failure to push the file to begin with
When I try to push a file like a rom.zip to /data I get,
❯ adb push rom.zip /data
adb: error: failed to copy 'rom.zip' to '/data/rom.zip': remote couldn't create file: Permission denied
rom.zip: 0 files pushed, 0 skipped. 92.6 MB/s (3538512 bytes in 0.036s)


It is well known that you need root permissions to access /data or a subdirectory.

Push to /sdcard instead
In newer versions of Android, you can not push /data. Instead the workaround seems to be to push to /sdcard
❯ adb push rom.zip /sdcard
rom.zip: 1 file pushed, 0 skipped. 28.3 MB/s (1345229325 bytes in 45.253s)


ADB never had R/W permissions to /data but to /data/local/tmp.
